# Kundera for Cassandra - Deleting record by row key

Tags: java, cassandra, jpql, cql, kundera

I'm trying to delete specific record from database by row key. But when I try to execute this query:

```
 Query query = em.createQuery(
            "DELETE FROM User u WHERE u.userId = :u");

 query.setParameter("u", userID).executeUpdate();
```

I got this exception: "*Condition = is not suported for query on row key!*".

Is there any workaround, or I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do as a workaround is:

Find using:
User u = em.find(User.class, userId)

and then,
em.delete(u);

Comment: wouldn't that cause a database read :(...in PlayOrm for cassandra and JPA, you instead do User user = em.getReference(User.clas, userId) and em.remove(user); so you don't need the extra database read.

Comment: em.getReference(User.clas, userId)

how would you obtain reference to actual record without toucing to DB even to populate in cache you need it.

Anyway other way is via executing CQL query. Also with 2.1 onwards such queries should work.

-Vivek

Comment: you can look at hibernate's code or PlayOrm's but basically getReference just wraps the Id without touch db, and then remove unwraps and sends in remove the row with id equal to that id so no read is needed from the database....sometimes there is no need to put it in the cache so I am not sure why you refer to the cache.

Answer (score 1):

Also,
http://groups.google.com/group/kundera-discuss/subscribe
can give you quick and better support to discuss issues around Kundera.

-Vivek

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach to perform such a delete (in one command using Kundera, version 2.2 at the moment) is to use "native query", for example:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cassandra_pu");

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

// "table" is the table name (case sensitive) you name your table in Cassandra
String query = "delete from table where key = 'keyValue'";

// "TablePersistencyEntity" is the Kundera Persistency Entity (Class) for the "table" 
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query, TablePersistencyEntity.class);
q.getResultList();

em.close();
```