# Kundera Cassandra Delete a row based on Indexed column

Tags: cassandra, kundera

How to delete rows in cassandra based on an indexed column ?

Tried:

upload_id is added as an index in the table.

1. `Delete from table where upload_id = '"+uploadId+"'"`
    But this gives me an Error `"NON PRIMARY KEY found in where clause"`.
2. `String selectQuery = "Select hashkey from table where upload_id='" + uploadId + "'"`

`entityManager.createNativeQuery(selectQuery).getResultList()`
and delete all the elements in the List using a for loop.
       This query is changed by kundera to append `LIMIT 100 ALLOW Filtering`.

Found a Question similar to this at [Kundera for Cassandra - Deleting record by row key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522120/kundera-for-cassandra-deleting-record-by-row-key) but that was asked in 2012 after that there were a lot of changes to cassandra and Kundera.

Answer (score 0):

Kundera by default uses `LIMIT 100`. You can use `query.setMaxResults(<integer>)`  to modify the limit accordingly and then run the loop.

**Example:**

```
Query findQuery = entityManager.createQuery("Select p from PersonCassandra p where p.age = 10", PersonCassandra.class);
findQuery.setMaxResults(5000);
List<PersonCassandra> allPersons = findQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: how to get all the results. Is there any way to getNextResults